# No contacts tracking in XConnect, anonymous or know, on standalone XP 9.2

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I have a standalone Sitecore XP 9.2 instance running (on prem) that has no contacts tracking in XConnect, anonymous or known. I've checked off all the normal culprits I can think of but they all seem to be OK.

In the configs:
Xdb.Enabled = true
Xdb.Tracking.Enabled = true

The layout includes:
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()

I've checked the Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager DB and confirmed the Database server and name are correct in the ShardsGlobal table

I've rebuild the Solr xdb cores and checked that the id:xdb-index-token is correct

XConnect plus the IndexWorker and ProcessingEngine services are running, certificates are all OK, and there's no errors in any of the logs

There is only one error in all of the log files:

> 5252 07:04:40 ERROR Cannot finish Analytics page tracking
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Source: Sitecore.Analytics
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.Robots.SetRobotSessionTimeout(Session session, HttpSessionStateBase contextSession)
> at (Object , Object )
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EndAnalytics.EndAnalyticsPipeline.Run()
> at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EndAnalytics.Process(HttpRequestArgs args)

I haven't found anything similar to the above error apart from one reference in the XP10 release notes about a resolved error:
The Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.Robots.SetRobotSessionTimeout method throws a NullReferenceException when it is called on a Content Management server.
TFS no. 302163

I have the same setup on another standalone developer instance and the XConnect tracking is working as expected. I can't find any difference between the working and not working server and I'm now at day 3 of trying to get the tracking working with no luck.

Is there any other setting I'm missing to get XConnect tracking enabled, or any hints about the SetRobotSessionTimeout error that might point to the issue?

Comment: I guess the answer is to ask sitecore support about this?